# Why won't my graphic update?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So i'm creating a simple program involving graphics for my high school computer science class and i'm having trouble getting the graphics to actually draw and update. On the JPanel, I would like it to draw parts of the hangman as the user fails to guess a correct letter/word as well as display and update the mysteryWord along the way (ie h-ll-, word is hello). On the terminal is where the user will input their guess.

Right now I have set it to just draw random lines. The only problem is it doesn't draw them. I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the the Hangman code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Hangman extends JPanel
{
    private String mysteryWord; //The hidden word "----"
    private String word; //The word to be guessed
    private ArrayList<String> bank; //List of words to be guessed
    private ArrayList<String> incorrect; //List of wrong guesses the user has made
    private int guesses; //Number of guesses
    private int drawing; //determines what to draw
    /**
     * Creates a Hangman object. word is the word to be guessed and mysteryWord is 
     * the word with all characters replaced with a blank "_"
     */
    public Hangman()
    {
        drawing = 0;
        guesses = 11;
        bank = new ArrayList<String>();
        incorrect = new ArrayList<String>();
        bank.add("Spain");bank.add("France");bank.add("Germany");bank.add("Vietnam");bank.add("Italy");bank.add("Portugal");bank.add("United States");
        bank.add("Argentina");bank.add("Canada");bank.add("Mexico");bank.add("China");bank.add("Japan");bank.add("Somalia");
        bank.add("Soccer");bank.add("Football");bank.add("Baseball");bank.add("Tennis");bank.add("Basketball");bank.add("Games");
        bank.add("One");
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * bank.size());
        word = bank.get(random);
        mysteryWord = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            mysteryWord = mysteryWord + "-";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Hangman object. The word to be guessed is a word chosen by the used and the mysteryWord is the chosen 
     * word with all characters replaced with a "-";
     */
    public Hangman(String str)
    {
        guesses = 11;
        incorrect = new ArrayList<String>();
        word = str;
        mysteryWord = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            mysteryWord = mysteryWord + "-";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the number of guesses
     */
    public void setGuesses(int x)
    {
        guesses = x;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of guesses
     */
    public int getGuesses()
    {
        return guesses;
    }

    /**
     * Makes a guess. The guessed word must have a length of 1, guessing one character or
     * have a length of the hidden word, guessing the whole word
     */
    public boolean makeGuess(String guess)
    {
        String updatedStr = "";
        String str = guess;
        boolean status = false;
        if(guess.length() == 0 || guess.length() > 1 && guess.length() < word.length() || guess.length() > word.length())
        {
                System.out.println("You can only guess 1 letter or the whole word");
                updatedStr = mysteryWord;
                incorrect.add(guess);
        }
        else if(guess.length() == 1)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            {
                if(word.substring(i,i+1).equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
                {
                    updatedStr += guess;
                    status = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    updatedStr += mysteryWord.substring(i,i+1);
                }
            }
            if(status == false)
            {
                incorrect.add(guess);
            }
        }
        else if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
        {
            status = true;
            updatedStr = word;
            guesses = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            updatedStr = mysteryWord;
            incorrect.add(guess);
        }
        guesses--;
        mysteryWord = updatedStr;
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the user's guessed string is equal to the hidden word
     */
    public boolean isEqual()
    {
        if(mysteryWord.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getIncorrectGuesses()
    {
        String wrong = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < incorrect.size(); i++)
        {
           wrong = wrong + (incorrect.get(i) + ", ");
        }
        return wrong;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the word the user has been guessing
     */
    public String getMWord()
    {
        return mysteryWord;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the word the user is trying to guess
     */
    public String getWord()
    {
        return word;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(mysteryWord, 25, 120);
        switch(drawing)
        {
            case 1: g.drawLine(23, 150, 200, 150);break;
            case 2: g.drawLine(23, 150, 250, 150);break;
            case 3: g.drawLine(23, 150, 300, 150);break;
            case 4: g.drawLine(23, 150, 800, 150);break;
            case 5: g.drawLine(23, 150, 70, 150);break;
            case 6: g.drawLine(23, 150, 40, 150);break;
            case 7: g.drawLine(23, 150, 10, 150);break;
            case 8: g.drawLine(23, 150, 50, 150);break;
            case 9: g.drawLine(23, 150, 20, 150);break;
            case 10: g.drawLine(23, 150, 90, 150);break;
            case 11: g.drawLine(23, 200, 200, 150);break;
        }
    }

    public void playHangman()
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Time to play Hangman!");
        System.out.println("Would you like to use your own word? Yes or no?");
        String play = kb.nextLine();
        if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            System.out.println("What word would you like to use?");
            String word = kb.nextLine();
            Hangman test = new Hangman(word);
            boolean status = false;
            while(test.getGuesses() > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Progress: " + test.getMWord());
                System.out.println("Guesses: " + test.getGuesses());
                System.out.println("Incorrect: " + test.getIncorrectGuesses());
                System.out.print("Guess a character or word: ");
                String guess = kb.nextLine();
                if(test.makeGuess(guess) == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong!");
                    drawing++;
                }
                if(test.isEqual() == true)
                {
                    test.setGuesses(0);
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            if(status == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Progress: " + test.getMWord());
                System.out.println("The hidden word was: " + test.getWord());
                System.out.println("Congratulations you win!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Progress: " + test.getMWord());
                System.out.println("You lost... better luck next time!");
                System.out.println("The hidden word was: " + test.getWord());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Hangman test = new Hangman();
            boolean status = false;
            while(test.getGuesses() > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Progress: " + test.getMWord());
                System.out.println("Guesses: " + test.getGuesses());
                System.out.println("Incorrect: " + test.getIncorrectGuesses());
                System.out.print("Guess a character or word: ");
                String guess = kb.nextLine();
                if(test.makeGuess(guess) == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Wrong!");
                    drawing++;
                }
                if(test.isEqual() == true)
                {
                    test.setGuesses(0);
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            if(status == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Progress: " + test.getMWord());
                System.out.println("Congratulations you win!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Progress: " + test.getMWord());
                System.out.println("You lost... better luck next time!");
                System.out.println("The hidden word was: " + test.getWord());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class the user will run to play the game

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Hangman player = new Hangman();
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Hangman");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(500,300);
        window.add(player);
        window.setVisible(true);
        player.playHangman();
    }
}
```

Eventually I will modify my code so that the only things that will appear on the terminal is the program asking for the users guess and receiving one as well as informing the user if their guess was right. But first I have to get my lines to actually draw as the user makes a false guess.

Comment: Everything is on the main (event dispatch) thread and so the graphics never get a chance to do anything because you're always blocking waiting for input. Conceptually using the console to give input to a graphics program is bad.

Comment: `while(test.getGuesses() > 0)` is a bad sign - GUIs are event driven, that is, something happens and you respond to it, unlike console based programs. Don't mix paradigms - `String guess = kb.nextLine();` is not how you get input from the user in a GUI

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is on the main (event dispatch) thread and so the graphics
>   never get a chance to do anything because you're always blocking
>   waiting for input. Conceptually using the console to give input to a
>   graphics program is bad. – John3136

I'm pretty sure John3136 got it right. You would be better off taking in the inputs from the user through swing components within the frame or in a different one.

If you still wish to use the console for inputs, calling the repaint() method *at the end* of the `paintComponent()` method works. I tried it out, and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update graphic (call your paintComponent method), call `repaint();`